# JDBC API forName exception (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: sql-server-2005, jdbc

I am new to JDBC application development. I am writing a JDBC application using Visual Studio 2005. I need to connect my application to MS SQL Server 2005. I have installed the JDBC driver 3.0. Also Java runtime version 1.6 is intalled on my machine.

I am writing a simple code to connect to the SQL server. I have set the CLASSPATH in inviromnet variable list. Here is the code

```
package MyJDBCApp;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Connect
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://NOI1-501791:1433;databaseName=test;user=sa; password=asdf1234;";
        Connection con;
        Statement stmt;
        try
        {
           Class.forName("com.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        }
        catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
           System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
           System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }   
   }
}
```

When I try to debug this application everytime I am getting Class not found exception. 
Can anybody help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Zubair

Comment: How you are trying to debug applicaiton? IDE or command prompt?

Comment: once check whether lib is there or not and you have included in project classpath or not.

Comment: Which lib you are talking about? and how to set it in project classpath?

Comment: you can downloa library from this url : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx and add this library to project classpath by rightclick on project and select java build path and add this library and run.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally not use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. It is mostly an artefact of the early years of Java. Usually programs have their own private classpath.

Inside IDEs the classpath is the project classpath (aka build path), outside the IDE it is usually the `Class-Path:` entry in the manifest of a jar.

The `CLASSPATH` environment variable will only be used if you run commandline without other means of setting a classpath (which is done when using `java -jar` or `java -cp`).

So you will need to add the JDBC driver to the project classpath. Also if you use the sqljdbc4.jar (which is the JDBC 4 driver in MS SQL Server JDBC 3.0), then you don't even need to do `Class.forName(...)`, as JDBC 4 introduced automatic driver registration.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to add reference to sqljdbc.jar in my project. I set the "Reference Path" of the JDBC driver. I am building Visual j# Console application. To add reference of sqljdbc in my project I right-click on "References" tag in my project and then press on "Add References". But can anybody tell me how to add reference of my sqljdbc.jar in my application as I cant find any way to add it in my project.

Comment: J# is not exactly Java, so I can't help you there.